# Mass Email Storage tools

Tags: email

Is there is any specific email storage tool that can store above 5Gb of emails which could be used with salesforce later

Answer (score 0):

I think you should integrate outlook with salesforce. Go through below link.

[https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewQuickStarts?id=000113374](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewQuickStarts?id=000113374://)